# весь кэш visual studio 19

Tags: visual-studio

При установке vs невозможно не записать какой-нибудь кэш на диск С. Допустим мне хватило места, но когда я удалил vs, мои 10гб(если не больше) никто не вернул -_-

Я искал в интернете и все что смог сделать это очистить пару гб.
Я просто не понимаю, где может быть еще что-то.
Может быть вместе в ней что-то еще установилось? Как мне это удалить?

Помогите пожалуйста! А то мне место на vs17 не хватает) Потому что vs17 еще 10гб сожрать хочет и ей обязательно диск С жрать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два приложения Visual Studio Installer и сам Visual Studio. Нужно зайти в инсталлер и посмотреть какие компоненты установлены удалить их а затем удалить сам инсталлер.

По умолчанию используются следующие папки

Visual Studio IDE
Это расположение предназначено для файлов, относящихся только к этой
версии Visual Studio. Если у вас твердотельный
системный диск, рекомендуется принять
расположение по умолчанию, чтобы среда Visual Studio запускалась быстрее.`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community`

Кэш загрузки
Visual Studio использует это расположение для скачивания файлов
установки. Вы можете не хранить кэш скачивания после
установки, но тогда вам потребуется снова скачать эти файлы
при обновлении, изменении или удалении продукта. Это расположение
можно задать только при первой установке Visual Studio.
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages`

Общие компоненты, инструменты и пакеты SDK
Это расположение содержит общие файлы для параллельных
установок Visual Studio. Некоторые инструменты и пакеты SDK устанавливаются
на этот диск, тогда как для других можно
переопределить этот параметр и установить их на другой диск.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared`